# Request for clarification about linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help understanding the basis of this statement in Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*, found on page 86 of the second edition:

*Because ($\vec{v_{1}}, \ldots, \vec{v_{n}}$) is a basis of $V$, we can write*

$\vec{v} = a_{1}\vec{v_{1}} + \cdots + a_{k}\vec{v_{k}}$

*where $a_{1}, \ldots , a_{k} \in \mathbf{F}$ and $a_{k} \neq 0$ (represent $v$ as a linear combination of ($\vec{v_{1}}, \ldots, \vec{v_{n}}$) and then chose $k$ to be the largest index with a nonzero coefficient.*

How can we assume that not all the basis vectors in $V$ need a nonzero coefficient to construct $v$ as a linear combination?  There seem to be so many clear counterexamples to this ($(1, 1) = 1(0,1) + 1(1,0)$) that I'm sure I've misunderstood something fundamental.

Comment: It *is* possible that $k = n$ and that you do use all elements of the basis.  Nowhere did it suggest that you used a strict subset of the basis elements.  The only difference is that if we are working in an infinite dimensional vector space, we require that an element be represented by a linear combination of only finitely many basis elements.

Comment: Thank you, @JMoravitz.  You're absolutely right.  I mis-read the proof in a way that made me think its conclusion required that at least one of the basis coefficients be 0.  I can see now that I was wrong.